# cannot import apps between eachother in Django

Tags: django-models, module, django-apps

I am relatively new to coding and am trying to do some stuff in django. im trying to have my apps reference eachother in django but i get the error "ImportError: cannot import name Question".What i dont understand is that when i create a new project and put 2 new apps inside it, i can reference the apps no problem

here is my project file structure:

[image]

and here is my code in my models files

signups/models.py

[image]

code from questions.models
[image]

and then my traceback from terminal
[image]

if anyone could take a quick look at this, i'd really appreciate it. I have checked a ton of other stack posts to see if any posted answers would solve my problem, but i haven't had any luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

so it looks like i figured out my own problem. it looks like it had to do with the file structure. originally, i had my structure like this:

virtual env > project > projects file > apps

it looks like it should have been this:

virtual env > project > projects files, app1, app2

Cheers.

Comment: Just kidding. didnt fix it. it looks like it has to do with the file structure though.